# Is there a Jenkins MultiJob like plugin to execute phases is parallel?

Tags: plugins, jenkins, parallel-processing

**Context**

My `Jenkins` job uses a `MultiJob plugin` which triggers phases with multiple jobs in each phase. It takes a long time for the entire build process to complete.

**Problem**

Our plan was to configure a `master-slave` setup to make use of additional executors. However, since the phase execution is sequential, all available executors remain idle and cannot be used to execute other phases in parallel.

At the same time, the concept of grouping jobs into phases is helpful for reporting.

**Question**

Is there a plugin which allows us to group jobs (like phases) but also allow us to trigger execution of these groups in parallel (NOT sequential like phases)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [workflow plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin) is where much of the development in this sort of use case is happening. You can do parallel execution, organize your phases into `stage`s, both inside and outside of those threads, distribute the phases across nodes as you see fit, etc.

You can even recycle those existing jobs using the `build` step.

Comment: I installed this plugin but I see that most steps are to be scripted.

Comment: In a multijob job, the phases are added as a build step while maintaining other configurations as independent steps like Post-build Actions, Build Environment, Build Triggers, Source Code Management, etc...

For Workflow, everything has be part of the script. Am I right or am I missing something?

I am trying to migrate an existing MultiJob job to something wherein I can execute in parallel as explained above, so I need to ensure I can replicate all the steps in the existing job.

Comment: Correct, Workflow codifies the job configuration almost entirely as a script. As a bridge of sorts you can use a special step called `build` in order to call your existing subjobs _without_ rewriting them in Workflow.

Comment: So then you need only worry about converting the controller job into Workflow. You can stop converting right there if you want. If it does little other than orchestrate the execution of subjobs, massaging some parameters, sending out email notification, etc., then it will probably be a very simple conversion.

If you want to go the whole 9 yards and eventually convert the subjobs as well, Workflow is undergoing rapid development but already supports many of the triggers and SCM wrappers "natively," and also many plugins and their steps via the glue steps called `wrap` and `step`.